# Changing the output column name in tsql

Tags: t-sql

We have a large number of price lists which are often dumped for review, my problem is not getting the data but labeling the output columns with the price list name so they make sense to the end user. Almost every time I run the query the combination of price lists change. The actual output is much wider than the simplified sample below making it rather laborious to go through and change all the individual column names. Is there a way to use the variable to label the columns as in the sample ?

(I am self taught in sql and consider myself to be at a basic level.)

Thanks for your time.

Mark

```
DECLARE @PrcLst1 varchar,
        @PrcLst2 varchar;
SET @PrcLst1 = 'RRP';
SET @PrcLst2 = 'Contract1';

SELECT PrdTab.SKU AS "Item Code"
    , PrdTab.Descr AS "Item Description"

    , PrcLst1.UOM AS @PrcLst1 + " Sales Unit"
    , PrcLst1.Price AS @PrcLst1 + " Price"
    , PrcLst1.StartDate AS @PrcLst1 + " Start Date"
    , PrcLst1.EndDate AS @PrcLst1 + " End Date"

    , PrcLst2.UOM AS @PrcLst2 + " Sales Unit"
    , PrcLst2.Price AS @PrcLst2 + " Price"
    , PrcLst2.StartDate AS @PrcLst2 + " Start Date"
    , PrcLst2.EndDate AS @PrcLst2 + " End Date"

FROM ProductTable PrdTab
    LEFT JOIN PriceTable PrcLst1 ON PrdTab.ItemCode = PrcLst1.ItemCode
        AND PrcLst1.PriceListName = @PrcLst1

    LEFT JOIN PriceTable PrcLst2 ON PrdTab.ItemCode = PrcLst2.ItemCode
        AND PrcLst2.PriceListName = @PrcLst2
```

Comment: Why not give the user 2 rows with the name as a column instead..? You can't value into a parameter into an object's name without Dynamic SQL, which seems silly for this. Give the User a normalised Dataset.

Comment: Also, you're missing the length for your `varchar` datatypes. **Always** declare your Length, scales and precisions. Otherwise you will end up with unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu, not quite sure I understand your first comment, if you mean add a column with the price list name, good idea, I hadn't thought of that but the full output is 55 columns wide, already too much scrolling back and forth so I'd prefer not to add more. If you mean a separate row for each price list, unfortunately won't work as later columns are doing comparisons between the price lists.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for the tip about the varchar data length, I usually, but not always, declare the length. Will do always in future.

Comment: But if you normalised the data it wouldn't be 55 columns wide, it would be 7.

Comment: You can't parameterize identifiers in SQL, and column aliases are identifiers. You could do it with dynamic SQL, but that's not a good enough reason to use dynamic SQL IMHO. Your best option would be to change the titles in your presentation layer.

Comment: @Larnu, Zohar thanks for your input guys looks like I'm stuck with modifying 'in post', but before I give up I would really like to understand what Larnu means by normalising the data, not something I've come across in this context. I'd be grateful if you could clarify or point me to a reference.

Comment: If your not familiar with Normalisation, you need to be, @MGD . It's fundamental in **good** database design. Perhaps here is a good start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Comment: Thanks @Larnu will definitely follow that up